# How do I use GnuDisassembler (gdis) in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra

I have managed to compile the GnuDisassembler Ghidra extension, but I only got a single executable, gdis. My questions:

Do I have to 'install' gdis in Ghidra, and if yes, how?

How do I use gdis from within Ghidra?

Is it possible to replace the built-in disassembler with gdis?

How do I 'enable' the additional CPU architectures provided by gdis (in my case ARC600)?

Comment: Some background info:



I first tried to activate the GnuDisassembler extension by selecting the 'File > Install extension' menu item. This simply gives a message advising that the extension has to be compiled first.



I then followed the instruction to compile the extension (inside the full Ghidra source tree and using a fork of binutils that supports ARC CPUs). The compile completed successfully, but as far as I can tell, it only created a single executable named 'gdis'. No extension ZIP archive was created that could then be installed from the 'File > Install extension' menu item.

Comment: I am using the Linux version of Ghidra (v9.2), although I don't think this makes any difference here.